# javascript not execute at live

Tags: c#, javascript

I am using Visual Studio. My javascript is functioning if I debug it at local host, the function is very simple, photo change at mouseOver.

But after I upload my file to my server, this function is not working. I have tried it on Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari:

```
function mouseOver1()
{
    var category1 = document
         .getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblItemID')
         .innerHTML + '_1.jpg';

    document
      .getElementById('<%= iPhotoMain.ClientID.Replace("$","_") %>')
      .src = 'photos/product/' + category1;
}

<img id ="photo1" 
     src ="photos/product/noImage.gif" 
     onmouseover="mouseOver1();"  
     class="thumbpic" 
     runat ="server" />
```

Comment: Did you upload the image also?

Comment: Is the ASP not generating the JavaScript you expect? If so, show us what JS you get and what JS you expect. Otherwise, if JS is what you expect it to be then the problem is with the JS, and you should show us the JavaScript and not the ASP.

Comment: yes, the photos is already uploaded :)

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are errors reported? Does the image change to a missing image or not change at all?

Comment: @Quentin , not change at all :)

Comment: Can you show us the markup for `lblItemID` and `iPhotoMain`? And explain what link there is between `iPhotoID` and `photo1`? I'm guessing the you have the wrong object ID's

Comment: @freefaller , there are 4 photos, photo1, photo2, photo3 and photoMain. so when the page load photoMain will loaded with photo1, whenever user mouseOver photo1,2 or 3, photoMain will change according to which photo the mouseOver. so i dun think the answer u provided below is correct. sorry i din point myself clear at the first place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In light of comments made by the OP, my original answer is partially incorrect (although I still don't think you should be using static ID for the `lblItemID` - so will leave the answer below).

My **new guess** would be that you have a *second* `mouseOver1();` function defined somewhere on your page, or more likely an external JavaScript file that you are linking to. So I would recommend that you check all external JavaScript files on your server that you link to and make sure they're as you would expect.

I can recommend [firebug for firefox](http://getfirebug.com) or the developers tools under IE and Chrome (F12 on both). With firebug you can breakpoint on the *next* Javascript to fire, so you can easily find out where the call is going to

---

**Original Answer**

My **guess** is that you have mixed up your object ID's. You are also using a static string to find one of your objects.

If I am correct, please try this - if I am incorrect in my guess, I will happily delete my answer.

(Note, I have changed `iPhotoMain` into `photo1`)

```
function mouseOver1(){
  var category1 = document
    .getElementById('<%=lblItemID.ClientID%>')
    .innerHTML + '_1.jpg';

  document
    .getElementById('<%=photo1.ClientID%>')
    .src = 'photos/product/' + category1;
}
```

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of when I saw the code. @melvintcs, what web servers are you using on the development machine and on the production server?

Comment: @Vedran , i develop it using win 7 + V.Studio 2008. My other codes/pages work just fine, even for other javascript code. only this script is not working.

Comment: @melvintcs, have you tried putting in a debug `alert("hello world");` at the start of the function? Is it possible that you have a *second* `mouseOver1()` defined somewhere that is only being picked up on the server?

Comment: @melvintcs, I would recommend [firebug for firefox](http://getfirebug.com) or the developers tools under IE and Chrome (F12), which will allow you to break point and see where the javascript call is goingo

Comment: @freefaller,  i put `alert("hello world")` as how u told me, and yes the alert did appears. but the photo is still remain, dint change. i dun think there is something wrong with the photo's id since it works at localhost?

Comment: Sorry @melvintcs, I'm using a tablet, which didn't show your comment before I'd updated my answer. i would try breaking down each part of the statements, and then use firebug to step through each line

Comment: @freefaller, i get firebug as u suggested (which is a very nice tool for debugging, thx!) i got this error `document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblItemID") is null`, but my lblItemID is already displayed "3", lblItemID is a label, and it get the value from the querystring at pageload

Comment: okay, this is weird, i removed `ctl00_` , now it's not function at localhost but it's function at server. so, is the ID problem. why the ID was changed after i upload to server?

Comment: @melvintcs, did you try using the `<%=lblItemID.ClientID%>` as I suggested?

Comment: Well done for getting it sorted, @melvintcs, and thank you for the mark

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on server your pages(data) coming slower than your local. So try callback functions with javascript. Like this..

```
    var category1 = "";

    function mouseOver1(callback)
    {
        category1 = document
             .getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblItemID')
             .innerHTML + '_1.jpg';

        callback();
    }

    function mouseOver2()
    {
       document
          .getElementById('<%= iPhotoMain.ClientID.Replace("$","_") %>')
          .src = 'photos/product/' + category1;
    }

<img id ="photo1" src ="photos/product/noImage.gif" onmouseover="mouseOver1(mouseOver2);" class="thumbpic"  runat ="server" />
```

Comment: thx for the answer, i have used ur code at localhost and server. Same problem, it works at localhost but not working at my website

Comment: use try catch in mouseOver1() function and watch with mozilla firebug or IE developer tools or chrome developer tools.you can find error..

Comment: ClientIdMode="Static" for you label. try something different.